# How to know if connection is made to a server using alias or not?

Tags: alias, serveralias

Is there a way to know if the connection to a host is made via an alias or using the direct host name itself? This is in Linux.

Basically I want to find out what are the connections made to my DB server host using the direct host name itself (and not an alias)

Thanks
SK

Comment: Connections are made via IP addresses not names.  You have no visibility into what name the client resolved to an IP from the receiving end.  If you want to know what names are being used, you need to look at the traffic on the client or on the DNS server (from the client).

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Is there any command or log on the client machine or DNS server that I can use?
Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Only if the application protocol  (the Database client ) transmits that information ( eg. http/1.1 uses host-headers to identify multiple websites listening on the same IP address )